# Can We install ubuntu 4.10 on virtualbox?

Tags: installation, virtualbox

Anyone has a idea how to install Ubuntu 4.10 on virtual box? My specs are:

- 4 GB Ram
- Intel core i3 64 bit@3.40 GHz
- Windows 8 64 bit
- Dell inspiron 660s

It is just because of curiosity.Another thing is I like testing out any OS with a graphical interface. And if you can,please provide a download link.

Comment: Why would you want to install such an old version? Is it out of curiosity?

Comment: Questions about end of life versions of Ubuntu is off topic. You need to ask this on something like ubuntuforums.org

Comment: Guyz,its just because of curiosity.Another thing is i like testing out any os with a graphical interface. and if you can,

Comment: please provide a download link

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: But is it supported for dell 660s?

Comment: probably, virtualbox hardware is quite generic and should work, but you're on your own here.

Comment: Its a VM. It dosen't matter. I have an instance of OS/2 running on a modern quad core system. Why not actually *try* it. Nothing bad will happen (usually)

Comment: @Anoymous if you want something as old as this you are on your own.  But why ask?! Why not just install VBox and download 4.10 if you can find it anywhere. You are on your own though >:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you *could* install it. I guess if it was in a VM it'd be *relatively* safe. The question is if it would be any use.

Download link here:
[http://**old-releases**.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/warty/)

**I do not support this and I don't think anyone else will either, you're on your own**

Comment: It should install fine - you might lack the ability to install any software outside what's on the disk without changing the repositories to the EOL archive repositories http://superuser.com/questions/339537/where-can-i-get-therepositories-for-old-ubuntu-versions